# How to output just the start tag via DOMDocument methods

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to print some HTML and I'm trying to figure out how I can print a start tag without printing an end tag. Is it possible to extract only the start tag?

```
$d = new DOMDocument;
$e = $d->createElement('div');
$e->setAttribute('class', 'example');
$d->appendChild($e);
echo $d->saveHtml(); // <div class="example"></div>
```

How can I make it output **only** the start tag (w/o using `preg_replace`)?

```
<div class="example">
```

Comment: DOMDocument only outputs well-formed html/xml.

Comment: DOMDocument only deals in valid XML. Is there a particular reason why you cannot use preg_replace?

Comment: @Asad I'm trying to figure out if it's worth using the DOMDocument methods vs. making a custom function that formats the attrs and prints the tag. I could use the preg_replace but if that's what's necessary I think I might be better off with a custom function that accepts the tag name and an array of attrs.